# (Struts2 - JEE) Usei extends de uma action class e na chamada da classe meu execute() não roda

Tags: java, aplicação-web, struts2

Então galera, eu nunca tive problema com o execute das classes de action do projeto, mas dessa vez quis reaproveitar o código de outra classe e ao usar o extends na chamada, ele só roda o prepare() e o validate().

Queria saber se alguem tem uma solução pra esse tipo de problema, o código da parte de chamada da action está logo abaixo:

```
public class AutorizarContratos extends GerarContrato{

    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        ...     
    }

    public void validate() {
        ...
    }

    public String execute(){        
        return "ok";
    }
```

E na action, simplesmente está:

```
    <action name="autorizarcontratos_*" class="teste.model.action.AutorizarContratos" method="{1}">
        <result name="ok">/view/autorizarcontratosconsulta.jsp</result>
    </action>
```